# Understand inotify events after cp command

Tags: c, centos, inotify, cp

I wrote a C program using inotify to monitor some directory ('a').
(Running on CentOS 6.5).

After running:

> cp b/txt_file a/

I'm recieving 2 events:
1) IN_MODIFY.
2) IN_CLOSE_WRITE.

After copying the same file again:

> cp b/txt_file a/

I'm recieving 3 events:
1) IN_MODIFY.
2) IN_MODIFY.
3) IN_CLOSE_WRITE.

Where did the extra IN_MODIFY come from?

---

#### Solved

I just wrote a sample program to test it:

```
int main ()  
{  
  int fd, wd;  

  fd = inotify_init1 (IN_NONBLOCK);  

  printf("fd: %d %d\n", fd, errno);  

  wd =
    inotify_add_watch (fd, "/home/geotool/a",
           IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE | IN_MOVED_TO |
           IN_CLOSE_WRITE);  

  char buf[4096]
    __attribute__ ((aligned (__alignof__ (struct inotify_event))));
  const struct inotify_event *event;

  int i;

  ssize_t len;
  char *ptr;


  for (;;)
  {
    /* Read some events. */
    len = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf);

    for (ptr = buf; ptr < buf + len;
     ptr += sizeof (struct inotify_event) + event->len)
    {
      event = (const struct inotify_event *) ptr;

      if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
        continue;

      if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)
        printf ("Created: %s\n", event->name);
      else if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
        printf ("Modified: %s\n", event->name);
      else if (event->mask & IN_DELETE)
        printf ("Deleted: %s\n", event->name);
      else if (event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
        printf ("Closed write: %s\n", event->name);
      else
        printf("dunno %s\n", event->name);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I recieved multiple IN_MODIFY events after copying files (with 'cp').
After some more searching, I realized that during copying large files, multiple IN_MODIFY events could be generated.

Answer (score 0):

1) IN_MODIFY. - directory event
2) IN_MODIFY. - file event
3) IN_CLOSE_WRITE. - file event.

Comment: All three were file events (with the same file name).

Comment: Is it possible that the first was for the 'old' file, and the second for the 'new' file?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html. Please have a look at examples it states :  Generates IN_MODIFY events for both dir and dir/myfile. Hence additional event.